# Adding multiple middleware to Laravel route

Tags: php, laravel

Per [laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-groups), I can add the `auth` middleware as follows:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function ()    {
        // Uses Auth Middleware
    });

    Route::get('user/profile', function () {
        // Uses Auth Middleware
    });
});
```

I've also seen middleware added as follows:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function() {
  // Uses all Middleware $middlewareGroups['web'] located in /app/Http/kernel.php?
  Route::resource('blog','BlogController'); //Make a CRUD controller
});
```

How can I do both?

PS.  Any comments providing insight on what the bottom four lines of code are doing would be appreciated

Answer (score 115, accepted):

To assign middleware to a route you can use either single middleware (first code snippet) or middleware groups (second code snippet). With middleware groups you are assigning multiple middleware to a route at once. You can find more details about middleware groups [in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware#middleware-groups).

To use both (single middleware & middleware group) you can try this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'web']], function() {
  // uses 'auth' middleware plus all middleware from $middlewareGroups['web']
  Route::resource('blog','BlogController'); //Make a CRUD controller
});
```

Comment: Ah, so `Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function() {});` and `Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function() {});` performs the same function?

Comment: Also, so the first code snippet isn't using group middleware?  The script includes `Route::group(...);` so I would apply to a group.

Comment: 1. Yes `Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function() {});` and `Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function() {});` performs the same

Comment: 2. The first code snippet is using 'auth' middleware, it's built-in Laravel middleware, not a group middleware

Comment: You're using `Route::group(...)` in both cases so in both cases it will be applied to a route group, not to a single route

Comment: I am going to assume (not checked) that `->middleware(['web', 'othermiddleware'])` will also work

Answer (score 30):

You may also assign multiple middleware to the route:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
//
})->middleware('first', 'second');
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware)

Comment: I had to put the multiple middlewares into an array: `...->middleware(['first', 'second']);` for this to work

Answer (score 8):

You could also do the following using the `middleware` static method of the `Route` facade:

```
Route::middleware(['middleware1', 'middlware2'])
    ->group(function () {
        // Your defined routes go here
    });
```

The `middleware` method accepts a single string for one middleware, or an array of strings 
for a group of middleware.

Answer (score 1):

```
Route::middleware(['auth:api'])->middleware(['second:middleware'])
    ->prefix('yourPrefix')->group(function () {
        //Add your routes here
});
```

Comment: Please describe what you are doing and move the `Laravel 7` out of the codebox ^^