# More then 2 middleware not working for group route in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-8, middleware, laravel-middleware

How can I add more than 2 middleware in the group route, I need to add 4 middleware at least. When I add only 2 It works fine but when I add more than 2 then It does not work.

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['middleware1','middleware2','middleware3','auth']], function(){
//My Indivisual middleware
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible cause would be: the other two middlewares were not added as a qualified class name. According to the docs : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware , you need  to define the classes for the middleware. In your question that is not provided so if thats the case you can check that.

Comment: Yes, I define those classes in kernal.php @bismark

Comment: I did a further search on this and found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40822882/adding-multiple-middleware-to-laravel-route). I hope it would be helpful. I think there could be a problem with the grouping of the middlewares for the route.